# Draw rectangles on Cube and remove

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 3d object as Wall ( Cube with texture and width and height large ) with some texture and attached c# ( Unity 5.3.2 ) script to that wall. I want to programmatically draw rectangles on that Wall with green semitransparent color and after 5 seconds remove them. I am new to Unity and found OnGui but it is not drawing in 3d space but in front of screen.
How to achieve this to draw and remove rectangles on Wall ?

Comment: Sadly your question is too broad.  Maybe ask over at [gamedev](http://gamedev.net).

Comment: Read up on procedural materials and procedural textures. They are historically used to make things like wood grain, marble, and tiles with user defined thicknesses and color at runtime as opposed to traditional image based textures.

[Procedural Materials](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProceduralMaterials.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **UGUI** (new unity gui system) and then set the canvas render mode to **WordSpace** . this way you can create rectangles on that canvas and set its position and width and height to fit on that wall .

And for animatins i would recommend you to use tweening engines like **Dotween**.